# DNN module development

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a client with dnn website. I need to develop module for it. How I can start? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 now (trial version). I cannot access source code, just make new module and install it. What is the best practice to start on the environment like this? Other question is if I using trial version of visual studio, is my module will expire too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Purchase and read this book: [Professional DotNetNuke Module Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470171162)
2. Visit the [download page](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Downloads.aspx) of DotNetNuke.com
3. Download the Community Edition. Install it on your dev machine, get it working.
4. Hook the Desktop Modules folder and bin folder (at least) to your source control
5. At the download page above, install the Visual Studio Starter Kit
6. Restart Visual Studio 2010
7. Start up Visual Studio 2010, create a new compiled DNN module project, make sure its location is in the Desktop Modules folder of DNN
8. Implement some test code
9. Install the module on DNN (install by manifest)
10. Add the module to a DNN page. Test it.
11. Make updates to your DNN module. You only need to uninstall and reinstall the module if you add or remove files or change the database setup scripts.
12. Build a deployable version of your module. (You make a zip file or something. Just read the book. I always have to refer back for this step)
13. Practice installing the DNN module on another fresh DNN Community Installation.
14. Once you are satisfied that it is installing correctly, install the module on the live site (Do backups first, just in case)

Answer (score 5):

These materials, especially video tutorials, might be really helpful to you when getting started with DNN module development: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Module-Development.aspx They cover every part from installing DNN module project templates to development and packaging of the custom DNN module.

To your second question, the answer is no, your module will not expire after VS2010 trial expires. Another option for you is to use free express editions of visual studio 2010, for this case Visual Web Developer 2010. You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express You will not be able to use source control directly from express edition, but still there is option to use SVN and a client like TortoiseSVN.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you follow the tutorials on this Wiki page. Use the templates listed there, not the ones from the Starter Kit (just trust me on that) http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com